# Usage of "Should" With Subjunctive or Without Subjunctive

Tags: modal-verbs, subjunctives

What is meaning of "should" in these sentences?

What are differences from other usages of "should"?

> 1. It's funny that you **should** say that. I was going to say the same thing.
> 2. It's only natural that parents **should** worry about their children.

Comment: You may be interested in the ELU question [*should: It's funny you should say that.*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206005/)

Comment: you shared link about first sentence but my second sentence is diffrent according to 1 @FumbleFingers

Comment: "Should" in your second sentence is **not** optional as in your first one since the meaning would differ. With "should", we are **advising** parents to worry about their children as parents are known for their kindness and sympathy, so it is a normal/natural thing for them to do. Without "should", we are pointing out the fact that parents **already** worry about their children because of their nature as parents.

Comment: @Tasneen ... Actually, you have highlighted that the sentence is ambiguous. It can be read as a piece of advice "parents should worry about their children" or as FumbleFingers said, it can just mean "parents worry about their children". The presence of the words "It's only natural that" tends to hint (although not conclusively) that it means "It's only natural that parents *are likely* to worry about their children".

Comment: @fred2 - I see now how can it has two meanings which are a piece of advice **and** the last sentence you provided. FumbleFingers's first comment has got deleted, but it wasn't mentioning anything about the OP's second sentence except in the last statement and between parentheses, he wrote something like _compared to the first sentence where the "should" is optional, the second sentence is not_. I have kind of used that to begin my first comment with.

Comment: Should vs. would. Should expresses obligation. Would;  implies a wish to speculative condition. Mood:  - is either Indicative, Imperative, or Subjunctive.  Compare definitions in Oxford. 1st sentence, mood is Indicative. Mood states a fact-his friend said it/he agrees w/it. Rules out Imperative/Subjunctive [ No prior command or suggestion prompting to say it.]   2nd sentence: Not Imperative (no command). Leaves this Indicative vs Subjunctive: Oxford says Subjunctive survives in sayings mostly; but almost indistinguishable w/1 grammatical rule how to find if it is or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you likely already know, the word *should* usually means that something ought to be done, or that there is some sense of obligation or morality involved. In these two examples, it does not have that meaning at all.

Instead, in both of these cases the word works as a substitute for an implied *did*. In modern usage

> It's funny that you should say that.
>
> It's funny that you say that.

have the same meaning. The word *should* is completely optional. The sentence means "I think it is strange or meaningful that you used the words you used."

*Should* has the same meaning in your second example. It essentially means "do."

> It's only natural that parents should worry about their children.
>
> It's only natural that parents worry about their children.

both mean the same thing.